# Angular 1.2.x console error messages

Tags: angularjs

I just noticed strange look of error messages in Angular 1.2.16 (and 1.3 beta also):

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/
modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%…g%2F1.2.16
%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dmyapp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20
Error%20(...<omitted>...1)
```

Instead of the ones in 1.2.1:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myapp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myapp' is not available! 
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 
If registering a module ensure that you specify th...<omitted>...0)
```

Anyone sees the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a cause of minified version.